# why is css transition working in one instance but not the other?

Tags: html, css

I am building a website just for css practice. I'm finding an instance of the transition property working correctly in one case, but not in the other. here are the two instances:

#1 hovering an image to transition to color from grayscale:

```
#banner img {
z-index: -1;
max-height: 10%;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
left: 0;

transition: filter .5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

and then the img:hover

```
#banner img:hover {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

this is working exactly as i hoped. but here i'm trying to change the color of a list element on hover and it's not making any difference when i hover:

```css
a {
  color: gold;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color 1s;
  -moz-transition: color 1s;
  -ms-transition: color 1s;
  -o-transition: color 1s;
  transition: color 1s;
}

a:hover {
  color: deeppink;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#staff" id="nav1">our translators</a></li>
    <li><a href="#work" id="nav2">our work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#why" id="nav3">why choose ozeki?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pricing" id="nav3">pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" id="nav1">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

i'm trying to follow the example i found here: http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/J6grS/1/

i previously tried to change the property over to the nav li{} which only has padding-bottom property, and its respective nav li:hover{} (which only contained the color to be changed to).

what is the difference that i'm not seeing in my attempts? any advice appreciated. thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Your code works properly (even if you should avoid duplicate `id`s). Maybe your problem is elsewhere

Comment: [here](https://codepen.io/crisz/pen/PEaOYg) is a *pen* with your code. As you can see, it works

Comment: @CristianTraìna thank you. good to know. i have had weird issues with display problems before. thanks

Comment: That bit of code works, so the problem in you full code must come from somewhere else, probably a specificity conflict. Use your dev tools to check which rules are being applied to your A elements on hover